# Particle interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment, statistics

According the experiments of interference of the particles one by one*, we see that it is the distribution of the impacts of all the particles on the screen (detector) which draws (constructs) the interference figure, does this collective "behavior" reflect the "character" of each of them or only a kind of probabilistic distribution?

What experiment can be imagined to prove that a single particle interferes with itself (thought experiment proposed by Richard Feynman ) without using the photon or particle count rate, i.e. a single particle that gives only one impact on the detector?

*https://youtu.be/UnZVFPdSoKY?t=3659

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ-0PBRuthc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e30BuTnhJng

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You cannot conclude statistical information from a single incidence. What you can do is repeat a single particle detection and then obtain a distribution of events. This has been done and the result is shown here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment.

Also particles do not interfere with themselves. It is is the wave function that exhibits interference. It is not collective behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, are the two slits neutral to the particles?

Comment: If we put a separator (thin layer of some micrometer) between the two holes without touching them until the screen, is that the interference persists?

Comment: Because I believe that the interference fringe are only the image of a ''field'' which exists between the two slits, this is why I proposed to separate by a thin film the two slits up to the screen so that it is not crossing paths, if the  fringe persist after the separation it is that the interpretation as wave does not hold the road.